# How to disable orientation React Native 0.61.5 App

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, react-navigation

I'm trying to prevent the application'ss rotation because when its rotated the app will restart all over. So my goal is disabling the rotation process. I tried lots of solutions but none of them worked for me.

**The issue is for only ANDROID**

I'm using *react-navigation: "^4.0.10*" - *react-native: "0.61.5"*

Here is my android manifest file:

```
<activity-alias
        android:name="REDUCTED"
        android:enabled="true"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:launchMode="singleTop"
  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the screen orientation to "portrait" for your main activity as well. It looks like you set the screen orientation for the activity alias but not for the main activity.

```
        <activity
            android:name="REDUCTED"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In my case I used multiple app icons that's why I used main alias but disabling that solved my problem!